# Installation Delphi 11.0 to 11.1. Update or reinstall?

Tags: delphi, installation

Searched but unable to find a clear answer. Is the upgrade from Delphi Alexandria a new installation (i.e. remove 11.0 first) or is it a simple "run to update"?

Comment: https://www.ideasawakened.com/post/rad-studio-11-1-alexandria-is-here-with-binary-compatibility-with-11-0

Comment: This post clearly states that 11.0 does NOT first have to be uninstalled, whereas the documentation (see answer @remy lebeau) suggests you need to do this...

Comment: From the blog post "If you have 11 Alexandria already installed, simply install this release and it will detect your existing installation and prompt you to uninstall the previous version and save your settings. "

Comment: @Darian Miller That's what I meant to say. The blog post is clear but the documentation suggests it first has to be removed. Simply running it also reveals it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.1 is still Alexandria. Embarcadero changed their version naming scheme for the 11.x series, where `x` is for updates, not major releases like in the 10.x series.

The Alexandria installation instructions states the following:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Installation

> Upgrading RAD Studio Alexandria
>
> > Attention: You do not need to follow these steps to install a different version of RAD Studio. Different versions of RAD Studio can coexist on the same system.
>
> To replace RAD Studio Alexandria with a better edition **or an update of RAD Studio Alexandria**, you must [remove RAD Studio Alexandria](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Installation#Removing_RAD_Studio) from your system and [install](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Installation#Installing_RAD_Studio) your upgraded edition **or update** of RAD Studio Alexandria.